# LinkedIn API for company followers

Tags: linkedin-api, zapier

I want to retrieve the follower count of our company via API requests. However, I don't understand the documentation on this.

I am using a no-code platform (Zapier) and this is what I tried:

- Account settings: My personal account
- HTTP Method: GET
- URL: [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:{organizationID}?edgeType=COMPANY_FOLLOWED_BY_MEMBER](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:%7BorganizationID%7D?edgeType=COMPANY_FOLLOWED_BY_MEMBER)
- Query String Parameters: Empty
- Additional Request Headers: Empty
- Body: Empty

The response I get is 400:

> The node type company did not match the required node type of member for the given edge type MemberToMember.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not correct.

The value of the `edgeType` parameter has to be camelcase as follows:

Example: https://api.linkedin.com/rest/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:(organisation_id)?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember

It will return:

```
{:body=>{"firstDegreeSize"=>51448}}
```